# Creating grid rather than a table

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

For the table below, rather than paginate, I would like to create a grid of results.

So I would like to echo out a set of 10 results, then continue the process 200 pixels to the right.  Then after 10 more results, continue 200 pixels to the right of that.

How can I do this?

```
$query2 = "SELECT street1, city, state, zip, phone, website
FROM addresses
WHERE submissionid=$submissionid
ORDER BY street1 DESC";     


$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

$arr2 = array(); 

   echo "<table class=\"commentecho3\">";


    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { 

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.strtoupper($row2["street1"]).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.strtoupper($row2["city"]).', &nbsp;'.strtoupper($row2["state"]).'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.strtoupper($row2["zip"]).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.strtoupper($row2["phone"]).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.strtoupper($row2["website"]).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '</tr>';

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '</tr>';

    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: you have to use css for that. use float property to align them as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really necessary to use tables there? Like Webgal suggested, could be really easy done using floated divs:
Create a class in css
    .foo{float:left;padding-right:200px;}

Update PHP (this can be done different ways):

```
$i=0;
echo('<div class="foo">');
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
echo '<p>'.strtoupper($row2["street1"]).'</p>';
  .................................
$i++;
if ($i=10){
  echo('</div><div class="foo">');
}
}
echo('</div>');
```